# Avoid javascript property names taking up memory for each object

Tags: javascript, memory-management, prototype

If I have a javascript object and define (say) object.myproperty = uniqueObjID, then I assume the word "myproperty" is stored as an entry into the hash table for each such object that is created. In other words, if I create 10 million of these objects, I'd have to allocate storage for the word "myproperty" 10 million times, since the compiler doesn't know whether object one-million-and-one will have a differently named property instead.

Wat's the best way to save memory by telling the js compiler that *all* objects of this type will have a "myproperty" value? Is it enough to do something like

object.prototype.init(ID){ this.myproperty = ID}

Comment: First, don't forget about string pools. Hardly a million string objects would be allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I create 10 million of these objects, I'd have to allocate storage for the word "myproperty" 10 million times, since the compiler doesn't know whether object one-million-and-one will have a differently named property instead.

What makes you think the compiler cannot differentiate between the million objects that do have a `myproperty` property and the one that has a differently named property? In fact, that is what JS compilers *do*.

For an example, have a look at the V8 engine's [hidden classes](https://developers.google.com/v8/design#prop_access) (even though they do a little more than a simple has table).

Comment: I was wondering if compiler magic meant that it didn't really matter? I guess I can assume so. Thanks.